# jquery ajax function freezing browser online but not locally

Tags: jquery, ajax

HI Programmers of the world.I have created a web application that does most of its staff via jquery and ajax. When I am loading content I use a link or button to call a function like :

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadusers()">View Users</a>

<div id="contentdiv" style="display:none;"> loading...</div>
```

I have an external js file that handles all functions e.g.

```
function loadusers()
{
    $.get('./users/allusers.php', {n:7}, function (responsetext) {
        $("#contentdiv").show('slow');
        $("#contentdiv").html(responsetext);
    });    
}
```

And php files that fetch data from the database and echos them in a table e.t.c
   //////////////

Now everything is working fine - atleast locally. But in a web server, when I click a link; it freezes the browser for a number seconds . sometimes upto 12 secs. almost all procedures including form submissions, file uploads, are handled by Jquery and ajax. Please tell me what am doing wrong.

-I am using local jquery includes  e.g. 
-Am loading data to divs using div id and div class
-Most of the popups are animated
-My page has very few graphics

Comment: Did you check to see how many results you are returning?  It's most likely your production database returning a larger dataset than your local database.

Comment: Hi Axel. The online database is infact returning less dataset than the localhost coz am using dammy data there. Even if Its one line being returned. Its still freezing.

Comment: Use your browser developer tools.  Script tab and Net tab to see exactly what's going on and where the bottleneck in your script execution is.